# Representing an imperfect ellipse in 2 linear variables

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections

I have several shapes which are roughly elliptical. I know the major and minor axes and the true circumference, so I store them like this:

$$a={\text{axis}}_{\text{major}}\\
b={\text{axis}}_{\text{minor}}\\
c={{\text{circumference}}_{\text{measured}} \over {\text{circ}}(a,b)}$$

(where ${\text{circ}}(a,b)$ calculates a circumference from the axes using an approximation formula)

Next, I linearly interpolate the shapes. This means that $a$ and $b$ are linearly interpolated, and it turns out that $c$ is also roughly linear. I want to get an approximation of the new circumference without actually measuring it. I do this:

$$a'=v a_1 + (1-v) a_2\\
b'=v b_1 + (1-v) b_2\\
c'=v c_1 + (1-v) c_2\\
{\text{circumference}}'_{\text{guess}}={\text{circ}}(a',b') \times c'$$

This all works fine, but I feel as though it should be possible with 2 variables, not 3, but I can't figure out how it would work. My reasoning is that the "fiddle factor" ($c$) can be merged with the eccentricity, leaving only the scale factor. Could this be done (while maintaining linearity) or am I mistaken? How would this change if I added the fiddle factor instead of multiplying?

Comment: Thanks @Bob for fixing the latex; I was trying to remember the command for text!

Comment: No problem..! :)